# PHP,CakePHP,HTML: The anchor tag is appended inside a code tag, how can seperate this anchor tag?

Tags: php, html, cakephp, html-table

```
echo '<tr class="class_row">';
echo '<td>';

echo $this->Html->link($post['Post']['title'],
                array('controller'=>'posts','action'=>'view',$post['Post']['id']),
                array('id'=>'id_anchor_title','class'=>'class_anchor_title') );
echo '<h6><i>'.$this->Time->format('d-M-Y',strtotime($post['Post']['created'])).'</i></h6>';
echo '<br/>';                           
$last_paragraph=$post['Post']['body'];
$length = strlen($last_paragraph);                  
echo $this->Text->truncate($last_paragraph,150,array('ending' => '...','exact' => false));
echo '<br/>';
//echo debug($last_paragraph);
if($length > 151){
    echo $this->Html->link('more',
                array('controller'=>'posts','action'=>'view',$post['Post']['id']),
                array('id'=>'id_anchor_more','class'=>'class_anchor_more') );
}
                echo '</td>';
echo '<td>'.$this->Html->link('Edit',
                    array('controller'=>'posts','action'=>'edit',$post['Post']['id']) ).'</td>';
echo '<td>'.$this->Html->link('Delete',
                    array('controller'=>'posts','action'=>'delete',$post['Post']['id'])).'</td>';
echo '</td>';
echo '</tr>';
```

The 'more' link/anchor is appended as a content/body of a post when I post something.

How can I make/put a break and stop 'more' being an element of body?

I got the following line as a content or body of a post, but it will a separate link.

```
<a href="/posts/view/37" id="id_anchor_more" class="class_anchor_more">more</a>
```

The link should be inside:

```
<table>
<tr>
<td>Content..Data.. <br/>'more' </td>
<td>Edit</td>
<td>Delete</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Can someone help me to fix this problem ?

Isn't possible to have the body and 'more' in same column `<td>` the problem is I'm using syntaxhighlighter http://alexgorbatchev.com/SyntaxHighlighter/, when I put some code inside tag `<pre class="brush: cpp"> ...body.. </pre>` then the problem occurs.

Comment: Couldn't get you. Can you please post your current output and desired output.

Comment: Current output is this => mysqldump -u root --password=mypassword databasename > backupfile.sql mysqldump -u root --password=mypassword...
<a href="/posts/view/37" id="id_anchor_more" class="class_anchor_more">more</a>
<a href="/posts/edit/37">Edit</a> <a href="/posts/delete/37">Delete</a>  But i want the 'more' , 'Edit' , 'Delete' as link/anchor not as a content of the post.

Comment: i got this code working just fine in my cakePHP

Comment: `id_anchor_more` should be unique; you're repeating it. Consider `id_anchor_more_<?php echo $post['Post']['id']; ?>` for unique IDs (If this is inside a loop of sorts; in any case it's repeat at least once.)

Comment: Yes, it's inside a foreach loop. So what's the problem with that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<style>
    table tr td h6{font-style: italic;}
</style>
<tr class="class_row">
    <td>
        <?php
        echo $this->Html->link($post['Post']['title'],
            '/posts/view'.$post['Post']['id'],
            array('id'=>'id_anchor_title','class'=>'class_anchor_title')
        );?>
        <h6><?php echo $this->Time->format('d-M-Y',strtotime($post['Post']['created']));?></h6>
        <br/>
        <?php 
        $last_paragraph=$post['Post']['body'];
        $length = strlen($last_paragraph);                  
        echo $this->Text->truncate($last_paragraph,150,array('ending' => '...','exact' => false));
        ?>
        <br/>
        <?php 
        if($length > 151){
            echo $this->Html->link('more', '/posts/view'.$post['Post']['id'],
                array('id'=>'id_anchor_more','class'=>'class_anchor_more')
            );
        }
        ?>
    </td>
    <td><?php echo $this->Html->link('Edit', '/posts/edit'.$post['Post']['id']);?></td>
    <td><?php echo $this->Html->link('Delete', '/posts/delete'.$post['Post']['id']);?></td>
</tr>
```

I think it would be easier to read by writing it this way, and i have tested this on my working cakePHP project, replacing `$post['Post']['body']` with some text with html tags in it, and it works just fine, notice that i don't change your original codes, just removing the echos.

i suspect that your  `$post['Post']['body']` probably contain something that make your link a plain text, try enclosing it with a div or something

```
<div>
    <?php 
    echo $this->Text->truncate(
        $last_paragraph,
        150,
        array('ending' => '...', 'exact' => false)
    );?>
</div>
```

Comment: The problem is during posting anything code i do <pre class="brush: cpp"> ..Code.. </pre> so the extra <pre>..</pre> tag is added with the post. I have used this , http://alexgorbatchev.com/SyntaxHighlighter/ the css and javascript here may conflict with the existing one.

Comment: I had to put all echo 'body'/message inside a <div> .. </div> , and that solved.

Answer (score 2):

The HTML structure is invalid. You're missing a closing `</td>` after the link.

This is also why it's a good idea to use [the HTML helper to create tables](http://book.cakephp.org/view/1435/Inserting-Well-Formatted-elements#tableCells-1447): it eliminates the chance of missing tags by mistake.

Comment: But in the wrong place. (You have two cells inside one.) Take a look at the generated HTML and run it through a validator.

Comment: I also noticed you edited the question to add the missing tag -- are you sure it's in your actual code?

Comment: Isn't possible to have the body and 'more' in same column '<td>' the problem is i'm using syntaxhighlighter http://alexgorbatchev.com/SyntaxHighlighter/ , when i put some code inside tag <pre class="brush: cpp"> ...body.. </pre> then the problem occurs.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
    echo '<tr class="class_row">';
    echo '<td>';

    echo $this->Html->link($post['Post']['title'],
                    array('controller'=>'posts','action'=>'view',$post['Post']['id']),
                    array('id'=>'id_anchor_title','class'=>'class_anchor_title') );
    echo '<h6><i>'.$this->Time->format('d-M-Y',strtotime($post['Post']['created'])).'</i></h6>';
    echo '<br/>';                           
    $last_paragraph=$post['Post']['body'];
    $length = strlen($last_paragraph);                  
    echo $this->Text->truncate($last_paragraph,150,array('ending' => '...','exact' => false));
    echo '</td>';

    if($length > 151){
        echo '<td>'.$this->Html->link('more',
                    array('controller'=>'posts','action'=>'view',$post['Post']['id']),
                    array('id'=>'id_anchor_more','class'=>'class_anchor_more') ).'</td>';
    }
                    echo '</td>';
    echo '<td>'.$this->Html->link('Edit',
                        array('controller'=>'posts','action'=>'edit',$post['Post']['id']) ).'</td>';
    echo '<td>'.$this->Html->link('Delete',
                        array('controller'=>'posts','action'=>'delete',$post['Post']['id'])).'</td>';
    echo '</tr>';
```

Comment: Then 'more' creates a new column '<td>' . Isn't possible to have the body and 'more' in same column '<td>' the problem is i'm using syntaxhighlighter http://alexgorbatchev.com/SyntaxHighlighter/ , when i put some code inside tag <pre class="brush: cpp"> ...body.. </pre> then the problem occurs.

Comment: @guru can you give us access (link) to your page so that we can see the problem ourselves.